# Add a numeric column to an SFrame in Glab

Tags: python, csv, numpy

In Graphlab,

I have a csv file which contains some_ids like the following:

```
  some_ids 
   10 
   92
   85 
   352
   ...
  65664
```

I imported the csv file into Glab as an sframe:

```
  my_csv = gl.SFrame.read_csv('my_csv_file.csv')
```

I need to add another column in the Sframe which contain the row number and I call it 'item_id'. The output will look like the following:

```
  item_id,some_ids 
    1       10 
    2       92
    3       85 
    4       352
       ...
   13373   65664
```

I do no prefer to create another csv whereas prefer to do this inside Glab. We can also use `numpy()` if needed. How can this be done please? Thanks

Comment: `my_csv.add_row_number()`  seem to be the answer however it make the row number start from `0`. I would like it to start from `1`.

Comment: ok. found. `my_csv=my_csv.add_row_number(column_name='item_id',start=1)` was the solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an inbuilt command for just that:

`graphlab.SFrame.add_row_number(column_name, start)`

You can find out more about it in the documentation [here](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.add_row_number.html#graphlab.SFrame.add_row_number)